# Extend colcon workspace without sourcing setup.sh

Tags: ros, ros2, catkin, colcon, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using colcon, is there a way to [Explicitly Specifying Workspace Chaining](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html#explicitly-specifying-workspace-chaining) without sourcing the parent workspace directly via setup.sh? With catkin_tools, there exists the `--extend`; is there a colcon equivalent? I didn't see anything of link in the migration guide:

https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/migration/catkin_tools.html

Or is sourcing install/setup.sh the conventional approach going forward?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312736/extend-colcon-workspace-without-sourcing-setup.sh/) by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1094 on 2019-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `--extend` option is define within [catkin](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/1d27d84d7a5e34c219da60f793ac22b2edf1c02d/cmake/templates/_setup_util.py.in#L252) which generates the setup files (not `catkin_tools`).

The [chaining of workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces) basically works as follows:

- If you build a workspace A without sourcing any setup file before the workspace A is not chained (so it can't use anything from other workspaces)
- When you source the setup file of workspace A and then build a workspace B that workspace B will overlay the sourced workspace A).
- When you then source the setup file of workspace B and then build a workspace C that workspace C will overlay the sourced workspace B and the workspace A).

What you can commonly not do is source two setup files. At least you won't get the result you might expect. Lets consider the following example:

- Workspace A was built without sourcing anything else before.
- Workspace B was built without sourcing anything else before.
- When sourcing the setup file of workspace A and then of workspace B the resulting environment will contain only the stuff from B. The reason is that the setup files will try their best to undo the environment changes from workspace A when sourcing the setup file of workspace B.
- Their are two options to get a "merged" environment:

  - Rebuild one of the workspaces with the other workspace sourced to chain them.
  - Source the second setup file with the option `--extend`.

After describing all this for ROS 1 finally getting to the difference in ROS 2:

The setup files in ROS 2 / ament do not contain any logic to undo changes of previously sourced workspaces. Simply because that logic is very fragile and likely to be incomplete in non-trivial cases. As such they also don't provide the `--extend` logic since you can simply source two setup files from independent workspaces and the result will be an environment containing both.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2